# Slicing images in PDF based on coordinates

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing

I have a [pdf](https://stackoverflow.tiiny.site/) in which the questions are to be sliced individually . I have tried [various methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882225/slicing-of-a-scanned-image-based-on-large-white-spaces/71882743?noredirect=1#comment127026201_71882743) with varying degree of success . Now the approach I am using is that , I have added a OCR layer on top of and found out coordinates of 101. , 102. till 200

Code I have used and sample output

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import re

# Open the PDF file
with open('document.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PdfReader(file)
    
    # Iterate through each page of the PDF
    for page_num in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]
        text = page.extract_text()
        matches = re.finditer(r'(1\d{2}\.|2\d{2}\. )', text)
        print("Page number: ",page_num+1) # added this line
        for match in matches:
            print(f"Number {match.group()} found at coordinates x1:{page.mediabox[0] + match.start()}, y1:{page.mediabox[1]}, x2:{page.mediabox[0] + match.end()}, y2:{page.mediabox[3]}")
```

Output

```
Page number:  1
Number 101. found at coordinates x1:185, y1:0, x2:189, y2:777.6
Number 102. found at coordinates x1:494, y1:0, x2:498, y2:777.6
Page number:  2
Number 103. found at coordinates x1:0, y1:0, x2:4, y2:777.6
Number 104. found at coordinates x1:144, y1:0, x2:148, y2:777.6
Page number:  3
Number 105. found at coordinates x1:0, y1:0, x2:4, y2:778.32
Number 106. found at coordinates x1:329, y1:0, x2:333, y2:778.32
```

My aim is to slice the pdf into images ,  taking vertices from top of page to 101. then 101. to 102. then 102. to end of page . Unable to proceed further . But unable to proceed further .

Comment: @KJ . 
//your 101 should be x1y1-x2y2=0,200 to 578,445 102 should be 0,445 to 578,702 if working image wise rather than PDF upwards and trim as required but depends on scale of units those are PDF points, presuming 778 ish high//

I am not getting the logic which you have used , Apologies. Could you please explain a bit .

Comment: I have added the code which i use to get it . The exact place where I am facing issue is to convert them into boxes for slicing . I am planning to slice them .

Comment: I am also using a PDF viewer. How do you see the pixels ? Is there a viewer to see it